# Why is my sidebar not showing up in ag-grid for vue?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I have the enterprise version of ag-grid with the license installed and appears to be working properly, but my sidebar will not show up no matter what implementation I try from the code on the ag-grid site. The enterprise grouping is working correctly and all of the other data input is showing fine. The table does not change at all if sidebar is true or false or any other setting.

Currently I have:

```js
import { RowGroupingModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping';
import { AllModules } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules";
import { ClientSideRowModelModule } from "@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model";
import { AgGridVue } from "@ag-grid-community/vue";

import '@ag-grid-community/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import '@ag-grid-community/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            columnDefs: null,
            autoGroupColumnDef: null,
            defaultColDef: null,
            rowData: {test: "Loading..."},
            rowSelection: null,
            rowGroupPanelShow: null,
            aggFuncs: null,
            gridApi: null,
            columnApi: null,
            sideBar: null,
            modules: [ClientSideRowModelModule, AllModules, RowGroupingModule],

        }
      },
      methods: {
        onGridReady(params) {
            this.gridApi = params.api;
            this.columnApi = params.columnApi;                         
       },
      components: {
            AgGridVue,
      },
      created(){
          this.sideBar = true;
      },
    }
```

```html
    <ag-grid-vue style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
        class="ag-theme-material"
        :autoGroupColumnDef="autoGroupColumnDef"
        :defaultColDef="defaultColDef"
        :columnDefs="columnDefs"
        :rowData="rowData"
        :modules="modules"
        :rowGroupPanelShow="rowGroupPanelShow"
        :sideBar="sideBar"
        :groupIncludeFooter="true"
        :aggFuncs="aggFuncs"
        rowSelection="single"
        @grid-ready="onGridReady"
        @column-row-group-changed="onColumnRowGroupChanged"
        @row-selected="onRowSelected"
        @firstDataRendered="onFirstDataRendered">
    </ag-grid-vue>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using the following:

```js
import { RowGroupingModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping';
import { AllModules } from "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules";
import { MenuModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/menu';
import { SetFilterModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/set-filter';
import { ColumnsToolPanelModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/column-tool-panel';
import { FiltersToolPanelModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/filter-tool-panel';
import { ClientSideRowModelModule } from "@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model";
import { AgGridVue } from "@ag-grid-community/vue";

import '@ag-grid-community/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import '@ag-grid-community/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css';
   
   export default {    
        data() {
            return {
               modules: [ClientSideRowModelModule, AllModules, RowGroupingModule, SetFilterModule, MenuModule, ColumnsToolPanelModule, FiltersToolPanelModule]
               }
              }
             }
```